# Symfony - EntityType rendering

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I have a form which have a field of type EntityType named categories that is showing like this :

[image: categories]

each one is placed in the bottom of the other, i want them to be displayed by group of 2 like this :

[image: wanted result]

anyone have an idea how to do that with Symfony and Twig ?

### EDIT :

here is the html code produced by the twig engine for that field

```html
 <form name="form" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="rechercher" class="btn btn-success">Rechercher</button>
    <div id="form">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label" for="form_motcle">Mot Clé</label>
         <input type="text" id="form_motcle" name="form[motcle]" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="control-label">Categories</label>
         <div id="form_categories">
            <div class="checkbox">                                                                     
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_1" name="form[categories][]" value="1" /> Théatre (0)
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">                                                            
               <label class="">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_2" name="form[categories][]" value="2" /> Cinema (0)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_3" name="form[categories][]" value="3" /> Comédie (0)
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">                                                            
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_4" name="form[categories][]" value="4" /> Spectacle (0)
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Changing the CSS of the existing code might already solve this, or use a custom method to render the fields in the template and then custom CSS

Comment: i'm not really that good with css so i didn't know how to try, do you have any idea ? perhaps there is a solution with javascript or jquery ?

Comment: Can you add the (relevant!) HTML that is produced (in the question please)? Even better: create a code snippet from it

Comment: it's done, i edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with a little CSS already. For information and usage of flexbox I always suggest [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

What this code does is basically the following:

1. Define `#form_categories` as somewhat of a container. Elements inside should be placed from left to right (`row`) and if they reach the end, should use a new line (`wrap`).
2. Each div which holds a checkbox (`#form_categories > .checkbox`) has a width of 50%, so you will have 2 divs per "row".

The advantage of an approach like this is that you can use media queries and change `width: 100%;` of a single div so it has its own row (e.g. on mobile displays).

```css
#form_categories {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
#form_categories > .checkbox {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
         <div id="form_categories">
            <div class="checkbox">                                                                     
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_1" name="form[categories][]" value="1" /> Théatre (0)
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">                                                            
               <label class="">
                   <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_2" name="form[categories][]" value="2" /> Cinema (0)
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_3" name="form[categories][]" value="3" /> Comédie (0)
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">                                                            
               <label class="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="form_categories_4" name="form[categories][]" value="4" /> Spectacle (0)
               </label>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: it's true they were all in the same line but the output was very weird, all checkboxs were above each other

Comment: @user6677 Can you show this (in a screenshot and best probably a fiddle)? Probably another CSS rule interfered